# How to assign value of variable with regex (bash)?

Tags: bash, string

I want to use regex in bash at line of variable assignment

e.g.

```
oldip="14\.130\.31\.172"
oldip_a="14.130.31.172" << How to use regex to del all '\'? and assign to oldip_a
```

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove the `\`, use bash parameter substitution.
`//` means replace **all** ... (a single `/` would mean replace only the first)
`//\\` means replace all `\` (backslash) chars
`/}` means replace with nothing (There is nothing bewtween `/` and the closing `}`

```
ip="14\.130\.31\.172"
echo "${ip//\\/}"
```

Output

```
14.130.31.172
```

Or, if there are many occurrences `\.` to do, in a file with many such IP addresses, you can assign each modified value to an array item.

```
ip=($(printf '
172.31.130.14
14\.130\.31\.172
33\.135\.220\.0
' | sed 's/\\//g'))
for ((i=0;i<${#ip[@]};i++));do
  echo "${ip[i]}"
done
```

output

```
172.31.130.14
14.130.31.172
33.135.220.0
```

?! .. I just noticed that your second data item is a reversal of the first.. Is that what you want as your output? (probably not, but it got me wondering)..

Comment: How to use regex in echo? Are you can explain to me?

Comment: cheers! that's a very nice answer.

Comment: @Peter.O : can you please explain me what {#ip[@]} specifies?

Comment: Regarding the _many_ case: “If parameter is an array variable subscripted with @ or *, the substitution operation is applied to each member of the array in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.” – man bash. `ip=('172.31.130.14' '14\.130\.31\.172' '33\.135\.220\.0'); echo "${ip[@]//\\/}"`